# constexpr int * vs constexpr const int * in C++ 11

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr

I have two variables outside of any functions (having the fixed address):

```
constexpr int j = 1;
const int k = 2;
```

Then I get their address in `main`:

```
int main(){
   constexpr int *p1 = &j; // ok
   constexpr int *p2 = &k; //error: incompatible pointer types of `int*` and const int*
   return 0;
}
```

I know that `constexpr` means it can be determined at compile time, and also implies `const` .

I think if `j` is a `const`, `p1` should be:

```
constexpr const int *p1 = &j;
```

And `constexpr const int *p2 = &k` works well as expected.

Then, why is **constexpr int *p2 = &k** wrong while **constexpr const int *p2 = &k** is ok ?

Comment: I guess that page doesn't really solve my questions. `constexpr int *p1` means **p1 is a const pointer to int**, and not `a pointer to const int`.

Comment: Or in other words, **why is `constexpr int *p2 = &k` wrong while `constexpr const int *p2 = &k;` is ok ?**

Comment: `constexpr` always applies to the thing being declared - it modifies the pointer. In your case, `const` modifies the pointee.